# Spring scope HashMap problems

Tags: spring

I've got a simple bean

```
<bean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap"  >
</bean>
```

I assume it has a singleton scope. But every time I call `getBean("map")` I get an empty HashMap even though it was filled before that.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably you are creating a new context every time before `getBean()`? Please show your code.

Comment: @Evgeni Yes, I do create new ones. It looks like I understood wrong the definition of spring singleton scope. I guess there's no way of using the same object with different contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application context is something that is usually created when the application is started and is destroyed when the application ends.
You can have the singleton working only in the boundaries of one application context.